# OAuth 1.0a “one-legged” authentication with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to make a request using OAuth 1.0a “one-legged” authentication with Ruby on Rails. How do I do that?

These are the two api's I would like to call:

- http://api.tuneefy.com/
- https://www.skyverge.com/blog/using-woocommerce-rest-api-introduction/

I am provided with consumer key and consumer secret.

Please note, I am referring to this specific OAuth protocol and not the others:

http://oauthbible.com/#oauth-10a-one-legged

Answer (score 2):

This gem works well: https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby

Install the oauth gem:

`sudo gem install oauth`

In your controller:

```
require 'oauth'

key = "YOUR_KEY"
secret = "YOUR_SECRET"
site_url = "YOUR_API_URL"
endpoint = "YOUR_ENDPOINT_URL"


consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(key, secret, {site: site_url}) 

# for a POST request
response = consumer.request(:post, endpoint, nil, {}, {})

# for a GET request
response = consumer.request(:get, endpoint, nil, {}, {})

# display response
puts response
```